# How can I encode labels in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I need to convert my string labels into vectors like [0, 0, ... , 1, ... 0]. 
As far as I could understand this is something that called one hot vector. 
I have 10 classes, so 10 different string labels.

Could anyone please help with direct and inverse transformation? 
I'm newbie in tensorflow so please be kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The forward direction is easy, since there's the `tf.one_hot` op:

```
import tensorflow as tf

original_indices = tf.constant([1, 5, 3])
depth = tf.constant(10)
one_hot_encoded = tf.one_hot(indices=original_indices, depth=depth)

with tf.Session():
  print(one_hot_encoded.eval())
```

Outputs:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

The inverse of this isn't too bad either, with `tf.where` to find the non-zero indices:

```
def decode_one_hot(batch_of_vectors):
  """Computes indices for the non-zero entries in batched one-hot vectors.

  Args:
    batch_of_vectors: A Tensor with length-N vectors, having shape [..., N].
  Returns:
    An integer Tensor with shape [...] indicating the index of the non-zero
    value in each vector.
  """
  nonzero_indices = tf.where(tf.not_equal(
      batch_of_vectors, tf.zeros_like(batch_of_vectors)))
  reshaped_nonzero_indices = tf.reshape(
      nonzero_indices[:, -1], tf.shape(batch_of_vectors)[:-1])
  return reshaped_nonzero_indices

with tf.Session():
  print(decode_one_hot(one_hot_encoded).eval())
```

Prints:

```
[1 5 3]
```