# How to reverse one hot encoded value to Label?

Tags: keras, one-hot-encoding

I am working on simple dataset to detect rock or mine with class names 'R' and 'M'. I have one hot encoded R to 1 and M to 0. Now I want to revese it.

I have tried many ways but couldn't find approach to convert back 1 to R and 0 to M

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keras
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

df=pd.read_csv('D:\\Datasets\\node-fussy-examples-master\\node-fussy- 
examples-master\\sonar\\training.csv')
ds=df.values
x_train=df[df.columns[0:60]].values
y_train=df[df.columns[60]]

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_train)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(y_train)
```

I expect 1  to be R and 0 to be M

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`inverse_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) method:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit([1, 2, 2, 6])
print(le.transform([1, 1, 2, 6]))
print(le.inverse_transform([0, 0, 1, 2]))
```

If you need to do the same thing in Tensorflow, look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092508/how-can-i-encode-labels-in-tensorflow).

Answer (score 1):

I just came across a use case today where I needed to convert an onehot-encoded tensor back to a normal label tensor. I know you can use `np.argmax(probs, axis=1)` or something to reverse an onehot-encoded probability tensor but that didn't work in my case as my data was not a soft probability tensor but rather a label tensor filled with either 0 or 1. I know this is not entirely relevant to OP's question but I thought someone might need to do something similar so I will just write my solution down here.

```py
def reverse_onehot(onehot_data):
    # onehot_data assumed to be channel last
    data_copy = np.zeros(onehot_data.shape[:-1])
    for c in range(onehot_data.shape[-1]):
        img_c = onehot_data[..., c]
        data_copy[img_c == 1] = c
    return data_copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `y` is your one-hot-encoded array. Then the following should give you the labels back:

> unique_classes[np.argmax(y, axis=1)]

assuming you used `unique_classes` for encoding too (order is important).